# Animating a growing ListPlot

Tags: plotting, animation, integer-sequence

I stumbled upon this (rather contrived but interesting) integer sequence. As it exhibits quite different behaviour at different scales, I would like to generate an animated `ListPlot` of it, where I'm changing the domain and range at an exponential rate to zoom through the orders of magnitude.

I've got *something* working but it's pretty glitchy and I'm having trouble getting the size of the points to shrink at a good proportional rate.

```
seq[n_] := seq@n = Module[{b = 2, l},
   While[! IntegerQ[l = Sqrt@Length@IntegerDigits[n, b]], ++b];
   Flatten[Transpose@(IntegerDigits[n, b]~Partition~l)]~FromDigits~b
   ]
plot[n_] := 
 ListPlot[
   seq /@ Range[n], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, n + 1}, {0, n + 1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.2/n]
 ]
frames = Rasterize[#, "Image"] & /@ Table[plot[10^(n/25)], {n, 25, 100}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

or ultimately

```
Export["sequence.gif", frames]
```

which gives

[image]

As you can see, despite the fixed aspect ratio and the fixed image size, the actual frames seem to have different sizes, leading to artefacts at the bottom. The axes are glitching all over the place as well, probably due to the changing tick labels.

Ideally I also want to increase the maximum `n` by another one or two orders of magnitude. I've also considered making the lower bound grow as well (so that I'm always showing a fixed ratio between `nMax` and `nMin`, since the interesting features of the plot are concentrated around the `seq[n]==n` line).

How could I improve the animation to get rid of the glitches, get a consistently useful `PointSize` and just generally make it look smoother?

---

**Edit:** I've incorporated some of the great suggestions in the comments. Here is my current version of the `plot` function, this time with fixed `PointSize` to show the issue of the increasing density. I've also adapted the code to only plot one order of magnitude at a time, because lower-left 10th of the domain isn't really interesting at any given scale:

```
plot[n_] := 
 ListPlot[
   {#, seq@#} & /@ Range[Round[n/10], Round@n], 
   PlotRange -> {{n/10 - 1, n + 1}, {n/10 - 1, n + 1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01], 
   ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]
 ]
```

And this is the corresponding animation:

[image]

However, that still has issues with the point size and the efficiency of the solution. As I said, I'd like to continue up to one or two more orders of magnitude, and the problem only gets worse, of course.

I also wonder if it would be possible to generate the full `ListPlot` only once (probably without any axes at all) and then generate an animation of a growing window into that `ListPlot`. I feel like that should be significantly faster to process, especially if I want to increase the framerate. Of course, that wouldn't make the `PointSize` issue any easier.

Comment: You want to add the `ImagePadding` option to the plot: something like `ImagePadding -> {{10, 5}, {15, 5}}`.

Comment: Perhaps you could eliminate the axes and their ticks. The ticks change so rapidly in the animation that I find them a serious distraction rather than aid to interpreting what is being displayed. Perhaps there is some other way to to annotate the plot that would provide contextual info and not be so distracting.

Comment: `ImagePadding -> {{50, 10}, {50, 10}},` will fix it

Comment: Note, there is no need for `Rasterize` here. Both `ListAnimate` and `Export` will handle the graphic objects.

Comment: "...get a consistently useful `PointSize`..." you have made the point size change with `n` so presumably by "consistent" you do not mean "constant". Can you clarify?

Comment: @george2079 I figured that for a large number of plot points, `Animate` would choke on the later frames, based on [this question](mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/is-it-possible-to-prerender-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch If I make the point size constant, their perceived thickness increases over time due to the increasing density of samples. So I wanted to make them shrink over time to compensate for that effect.

Comment: @m_goldberg That's a very good suggestion, thank you. I think I'd like to keep the axes to retain a bit more context on the scaling rate, but I've removed the labels, which helps a lot. The `ImagePadding` suggestion by march and Mike also fixed the glitches. What remains now is the point size. [Here is the current version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fpfRB.gif) where, for comparison, I've made the `PointSize` constant.

Comment: Please add your new code as an update to your question, so we can have the latest code to work with to attack the point size scaling issue.

Comment: @m_goldberg Oh of course, sorry. Edited in the new `plot` function as well as an updated gif. I could also replace the original code and gif completely, but I figured that an answer addressing all of these issues could be more useful to future readers.

Comment: Martin - please make this a self-answer, so users don't come to the question thinking it hasn't been answered and find the answer in the question. By the way, cool animation!

Comment: @Verbeia I would but I don't think my problem is quite solved yet. If I find a solution for the point size and the efficiency I'm happy to shift everything into a self-answer, but currently I specifically don't want to give the impression that my question has been fully answered yet. I'll have to look into this some more tomorrow.

Comment: What about  `pts[n_] := {#, seq@#} & /@ Range[1, Round@n]
    
    Manipulate[
     Graphics[
      {Dynamic@AbsolutePointSize[2/Log10@n], Point[pts[10^5]]},
      Frame -> True,
      PlotRange -> Dynamic@{{n/10 - 1, n + 1}, {n/10 - 1, n + 1}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 800, 
      ImagePadding -> 2 {{10, 10}, {10, 10}},
      PlotRangeClipping -> True],
     {n, 10, 10^5}
     ]`

Comment: @Kuba I'll give your point size scaling a spin later today, but I don't think Manipulate is practical for me, because I ultimately want a gif.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Drop Dynamic and replace Manipulate with Table and you are free to export it as a gif.

Comment: @Kuba oh, I just noticed you've replaced the ListPlot with Graphics and Point primitives. That's a good idea, I'll check that out as well. Might be a few hours though before I have access to Mathematica.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Take your time, see you later :)

Comment: @Kuba I kept getting distracted from this, but I just tried it and it works quite well. The perceived density still changes a bit, but it's much better.

Comment: @MartinBüttner feel free to use it for self answer :)

Answer (score 6):

In cases like this, you might have better results using `AbsolutePointSize` rather than `PointSize`, which plots things as a proportion of the plot area.

```
plot[n_] := 
 ListPlot[{#, seq@#} & /@ Range[Round[n/10], Round@n], 
  PlotRange -> {{n/10 - 1, n + 1}, {n/10 - 1, n + 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[2], 
  ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]]

frames = Rasterize[#, "Image"] & /@ 
   Table[plot[10^(n/25)], {n, 25, 100}];

Export["aps.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Depending on how much shrinkage you want for the point sizes, you could also consider scaling the `AbsolutePointSize` by `n` in some way.

```
plot[n_] := 
 ListPlot[{#, seq@#} & /@ Range[Round[n/10], Round@n], 
  PlotRange -> {{n/10 - 1, n + 1}, {n/10 - 1, n + 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[2/(0.05 n)], 
  ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As for the point size problem, I got what I thought a better looking plot by simply removing `PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]` from the definition of `plot`. Here it how it looks for large `n`.

```
plot[10000]
```

[image: plot10000]

```
plot[10000]
```

[image: plot100000]

Comment: This is what I had originally, and I found that there were noticeable skips in point size during the animation (which is why I specified the `PointSize` in the first place). However, now that the other glitches are removed this seems to be much less of a problem.