# How to add data to an existing plot?

Tags: plotting

Sometimes I need to plot functions that take quite a while to calculate--and sometimes I need to replot in light of what I see on the plot.  Is it possible to add points to a plot one by one, as they are calculated, so that I can preview how its coming out?

In the code below, I calculate a function at 240 values of x.  If I replot after every point, I'll end up with a series of 240 plots, which is not what I want.  Is it possible to just draw one plot and add the newly-calculated points to it?

```
z[n_, x_] := Nest[#^2 + x &, x, n];
center = -1.40115518909205`60;
side = N[(3*10^-15), 60];
steps = 120;
stepSize = side/steps;
a = Table[z[-1 + 2^28, center + n*stepSize], {n, -steps, steps}];
ListPlot[a, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small], DataRange -> {-side, side}]
```

(If anyone has some tips on speeding this calculation up, that would also be appreciated.)

Comment: closely related: [Is there a better way to add elements to a Graphics expression repeatedly?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46746/5478) and related: [Animating a growing ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100939/5478)

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted to only ever have one plot the two ways come to mind. One is similar to @bbgodfrey's method but incorporating some front end code to delete the previous plot. The other is to make the plot dynamic:

```
a = Table[n, {n, -20, 20}];
Dynamic[ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-1, 1}], TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

Now every time you change `a` the plot will change. The example below is quick and dirty. I've used `Flatten` to modify `a` but there are many other ways: `Join`, `Append`, `Prepend` and so on.

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

there are a few ways to do it without using dynamic. Here is a [reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/overwrite-contents-of-a-cell) to something @Kuba posted:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellTags -> "target"]
```

then

```
NotebookWrite[Cells[CellTags -> "target"][[1]], 
 Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-1, 1}]], "Input", 
  CellTags -> "target"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Dynamic is totally new to me, so I'll have to check this out.  What's that other method you mentioned?  How would one delete a plot and draw a new one where it was?

Comment: The other method would be to use `SelectionMove` to go back and select the previous plot and delete it. The above is cleaner

Comment: Is one of these methods any better/cleaner than using Dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic had the potential to add a point without updating the entire graphic so there could possibly be faster for large data. in the current answer both methods render a new plot each change

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you wish to add points to an existing plot without using `Show`.  Consider the toy problem,

```
a = Table[n, {n, -20, 20}];
plt = ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

To add

```
newpoint = {1, 10}
```

do the following.

```
pts = Join[Catenate@Cases[plt, Point[z_] -> z, Infinity], {newpoint}];
plt /. Point[_] -> Point[pts]
```

[image]

which contains the new point, as desired.  Additional points can be added by `Join`ing or `Append`ing them to pts.

**Addendum**

To have only one `Plot` displayed in the notebook, use

```
a = Table[n, {n, -20, 20}];
plt = ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-1, 1}];
Dynamic[plt]
```

which displays the first plot above.  Then

```
newpoint = {1, 10};
plt = plt /. Point[z_] :> Point[Append[z, newpoint]];
```

will cause the first plot to be replaced by the second.

Comment: No, that's not adding the point to the already-drawn plot, that's redrawing the plot with a new point.  If I do this after each of 240 new points, I'll have a series of 240 plots scrolling past.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP:  This is just a demo of the Dynamic[] method Mike recommended above.  This is exactly the effect I wanted to create for when I'm looking at a bifurcation point of a slooow calculation.

```
(* Function and endpoints *)
z[n_, c_] := Nest[#^2 + c &, c, n];
center = -1.40115518909205`60;
delta = N[(1*10^-12), 60];
r=22;
f[x_] := z[-1 + 2^r, center + x];


(*This array t makes the data pts fill in from the centre out, in layers*)
t = Flatten[{-1, 1, 0, Table[Table[{-i, i}, {i, 1, -1 + 2^j, 2}]/(2^j), {j, 1, 6}]}];

(* Initialize the plot with the first, middle, last points *)
fml = delta*{-1, 0, 1} ; a = Transpose[{fml, f[fml]}];
Dynamic[ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-delta, delta}], TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
Do[
    x = t[[i]]*delta;
    AppendTo[a, {x, f[x]}], {i, 1, Length[t]}]
```

Give it a few seconds, because it's slow (which was the point of all this), and depending on how you change the parameters the initial plot might not plot because of values of f[x] with no sig figs.  If it's too slow on your computer, decrease r a bit.  Sorry, I don't know how to create/upload a cool animation like Mike did.

[image: fadeIn]