# Pitfalls of running multiple Mathematica kernels?

Tags: dynamic, kernel

I've recently started running long calculations in one *Mathematica* kernel while I continue to work in another kernel.  I thought this was safe, but yesterday I was running [THIS CODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108292/20042) in which a `ListPlot` is dynamically updated as new points are calculated and added to an array I (foolishly) named `a`.

```
Dynamic[ListPlot[a, DataRange -> {-delta, delta}], TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

Then I (foolishly) created a variable `a` in my OTHER kernel, and down the tubes everything went.  The `ListPlot` displayed in my first kernel vanished, along with all the points I'd painstakingly calculated and stored in `a`.

It hadn't occurred to me that I couldn't have same-named variables in different kernels, but now I know better.  Is this only a problem when there's a dynamic object in one kernel?  Are there other pitfalls we should be aware of?

Comment: I don't get same issue. check this if it helps: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12425

Comment: Use different contexts as well as different kernels in the two instances of Mathematica to reduce the chance of cross-talk.