# How can I do a plot in real time as data is created?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

First, I have this two functions

```
fun1[x_] = Assuming[x > 0 && x ≤ 1, 0.5((Log[x/2])^2 - (ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]])^2)]
```

and

```
fun2[x_] = Assuming[x > 1, 0.5((Log[x/2]^2 + (ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]])^2)]
```

both function define a new piecewise function

```
funtot[x_] = Piecewise[{{fun1[x], x > 0 && x < 1}, {fun2[x], x > 1}}]
```

I need to define this last function because a I needed in this next numeric integral

```
F1[y_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := -I * w * Exp[0.5 * w * y^2] *
NIntegrate[x*(BesselJ[0, w * x * y])* Exp[I * w * (0.5 * x^2 - funtot[x] + 
0.0243401)],
{x, 0.001, g}, WorkingPrecision → 16, MaxRecursion → 30,
Method → {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases → 10 000}]
```

as you can see its a complex function, with "*y*", "*w*" and "*g*" parameters. Now with the next order can I create a table  called tabreal1 with *y* = *0.1*, *g* = *0.9999* and *w* runing on the interval (*0.001,100*) in steps size of *0.01*

```
tabreal1 = Table[{w, Abs[F1[0.1, w, 0.9999]]}, {w, 0.001, 100, 0.01}]
```

Mathematica, as you can see in the next image, show me the table *tabreal1* in this way because is too big (almost ten thousend couple values), and take almost like one hour

[image]

with the next algoritm, Mathematica take the table *tabreal1* and plot that table in a *LogLogPlot*

```
NFW1b = ListLogLogPlot[tabreal1, Frame->True, PlotRange->{{0.001, 100}, 
{.25, 10}},
AspectRatio->1, ImageSize->Large, FrameTicks->All,
GridLines->Automatic, PlotStyle->Black, PlotMarkers->{Automatic, 2}]
```

seconds later, this is the plot

[image]

There is some way to create that plot in real time as the table *tabreal1* is created? thats it, as Mathematica found some $(w_{1},F1_{1})$ Mathematica puts it immediately in the graph and I can see it, and seconds later when Mathematica found another $(w_{2},F1_{2})$ value Mathematica put in the graph and so on...

I need to require this because I need to make the step size of *w* smaller, actually with the step size of *0.001* the time taken to do *tabreal1* was almost ten hours, I guess with the visual aspect as the graph is crated can figure how time is remaining.

According to Wolfram Documentation center, the command *Dynamic* can help me to do this, but not work at all.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See also: [Is there a better way to repeatedly add elements to a Graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46746/27951), [Animating a growing ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100939/27951), [Dynamic plot with synchronization of real time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102860/27951).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simplified example. The function `slowfun` below is intentionally slow, to stand in for your long calculation.

```
ClearAll[slowfun]
slowfun[x_] := (Pause[1]; x^2)

Dynamic[ListLinePlot[
  table,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, 100}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1],
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
]

table = {}; x = -10;
While[x <= 10,
  table = AppendTo[table, {x, slowfun[x]}];
  x++
]
```

[image: animation]

Answer (score 4):

By constructing a table of points by hand with even spacing throughout, you waste a lot of time on regions of the function that are essentially flat. When possible, it is often good to take advantage of the excellent adaptive methods available internally to the `Plot` functions, which will sample the function more thoroughly only were needed.

Here is your code, slightly refactored:

```
Clear[F1, funtot]

funtot[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {0.5 Log[x/2]^2 - ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]^2, 0 < x < 1},
    {0.5 Log[x/2]^2 + ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]]^2, x > 1}}];

F1[y_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] :=
 -I w Exp[0.5 w y^2] NIntegrate[
   x BesselJ[0, w x y] Exp[I w (0.5 x^2 - funtot[x] + 0.0243401)], {x,0.001, g}]

plot = 
  LogLogPlot[
     Abs@F1[0.1, w, .9999], {w, 0.1, 100},
     Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.001, 100}, {.1, 2}},
     AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Large, FrameTicks -> All,
     GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black,
     Exclusions -> None
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In particular, I removed your request for higher working precision, which seemed ineffective, since many function arguments were given at machine precision (e.g. `0.5`, etc). I also let `NIntegrate` automatically select a method as a first attempt; since the automatic method seemed to work fine, I did not modify it further.

Timing using `AbsoluteTiming@LogLogPlot[...]` shows **it only took 27 seconds** to generate the plot above, instead of hours. `Plot` did not spend much time in those regions where the function is essentially a straight line, but concentrated its efforts in regions of high curvature. Here are the points that were actually sampled:

```
plot /. Line[l_] :> Through[{{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[#]} &, Line}[l]]
```

[image: with points]

Comment: Since `func1 ==func2`  for `x>0` you can take fun1 instead of funtot and accellerate calculation by 30 percent.  `fun1[x] - fun2[x] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  FullSimplify[#, x > 0] & ` yields  ` (*   0   *) `

Answer (score 0):

`Monitor` works reasonably well for that.

```
fun1[x_] = Assuming[x > 0 && x <= 1, 0.5 (Log[x/2]^2 - ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]^2)]
fun2[x_] =  Assuming[x > 1, 0.5 (Log[x/2]^2 + (ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]])^2)]
funtot[x_] = Piecewise[{{fun1[x], x > 0 && x < 1}, {fun2[x], x > 1}}]
F1[y_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] :=
 -I*w*Exp[0.5*w*y^2]*NIntegrate[
   x*(BesselJ[0, w*x*y])*Exp[I*w*(0.5*x^2 - funtot[x] + 0.0243401)], {x, 0.001, g}
  ]

tabreal1 = {};
Monitor[
 For[w = .001, w <= 100, w += .01, AppendTo[tabreal1, {w, Abs[F1[0.1, w, 0.9999]]}]], 
 ListLogLogPlot[tabreal1, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.001, 100}, {.25, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameTicks -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}
 ]
]
```

I've removed your `WorkingPrecision` and `Method` options as they resulted in

```
 NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s)
```

kind of errors in my case (11.0 on Windows 10). The result still looks identical to yours, at least in the range you plotted it.